# What is the relevant phenomenon behind Undulatus/Radiatus cloud formations?

Tags: waves, atmospheric-science, turbulence

I am seeing many people claiming that cumulus clouds that sometimes form periodic wavy patterns (see images for "altocumulus undulatus" or "Radiatus" for instance) have no explanation aside from being chemtrails, and I'd like to be able to respond with a sound scientific explanation.
I'd like to understand the phenomenon and my guess is that it's about the cloud blanket being forced by winds with the result of a periodic pattern appearing, much like sand waves form in shallow water at the beach.
But is it really the case? Searching for a more detailed explanation I ran into Tollmien-Schlichting waves that are a path to turbulence, but I admit I did not understand much, so here is my question(s):

1. What is the physics behind such cloud formations? And
2. Given an estimate of the spatial period of these cloud waves and the cloud height, can one infer the windspeed at that height?

Comment: I recommend removing the reference to "chemtrails", but if it is kept,  a few example links should be given to the "many people". Are you sure you are interested in [undulatus clouds](https://cloudappreciationsociety.org/cloud-library/undulatus/)  and not [radiatus clouds](https://cloudappreciationsociety.org/cloud-library/radiatus/)? Neither cloud type has anything to do with chemtrails,  but I think radiatus clouds would be more suspicious looking to [chemtrail conspiracists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemtrail_conspiracy_theory).

Comment: The reference to chemtrail is to justify the interest in the question: my aim is to respond to conspiracists on the topic.

Comment: @DavidBailey I edited the question: I did not know about Radiatus cloud formation, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a variety of cloud wave patterns, including  [radiatus](https://cloudappreciationsociety.org/cloud-library/radiatus/), [undulatus](https://cloudappreciationsociety.org/cloud-library/undulatus/), and [gravity wave clouds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_cloud). Their causes are not mysterious, but [fluid mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_mechanics) is rarely simple.  When air rises and falls in a pattern, clouds form at the high points if the air reaches the [lifted condensation level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifted_condensation_level).  The spatial period of the clouds does not in general depend just on wind speed and height, so they cannot easily be used to estimate the wind speed at height.

**Radiatus clouds** (also known as ["cloud streets"](https://www.eoas.ubc.ca/courses/atsc113/flying/met_concepts/02-met_concepts/02f-soaring/index.html) or ["horizontal convective rolls"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_convective_rolls)) are lines of thermal-updraft-top clouds which form parallel to the wind direction. The wind lines up the convective cells to form [horizontal convective rolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_convective_rolls) as shown in this [image from Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Convrolls.PNG):

[image: Schematic of horizontal convective rolls in the atmosphere in the production of cloud streets.]

The clouds form if the rising air reaches the [lifted condensation level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifted_condensation_level) before the updrafts are stopped by an inversion or stable layer. The air is (relatively) clear above the downdrafts.  If the convection rolls were perfectly circular, the cloud row spacing would be twice the height of the inversion/stable layer.

Mathematically, there are many wavelength solutions to convection, but the wavelength that dominates is the fastest growing one. In the [Boussinesq approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boussinesq_approximation_(buoyancy)), which is reasonably valid here, this turns out to have a wavelength of $2\sqrt{2}\sim 3$ times the height of the convecting layer, i.e. slightly flattened. (See, for example, Eq. 21 of [Kuettner (1971) "Cloud bands in the earth's atmosphere: Observations and Theory"](https://doi.org/10.3402/tellusa.v23i4-5.10519).)
For typical [cumulus cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulus_cloud) heights of $\sim 2$ km, we expect typical spacings of about $6$ km.

**Wave, lee, or mountain clouds** are lines of clouds downwind of an obstacle (such as a mountain range). The lines are parallel to the wind direction. These are buoyancy waves where wind pushes denser air over an obstacle (e.g. a mountain range) and it ends up above less dense air on the other side. This dense air starts to fall but it overshoots into even higher density air at lower altitude, which forces it back up, and the air ends up bouncing up and down until the oscillations die out.  If the vertical temperature profile of the air then is known, it is possible to estimate the [vertical buoyancy angular frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brunt%E2%80%93V%C3%A4is%C3%A4l%C3%A4_frequency)
$$N=\sqrt{\frac{g}{\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dz}}$$
where $g$ is the local acceleration due to gravity, $\theta$ is the atmosphere's [potential temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_temperature), and $z$ is the height.  Since this is the vertical oscillation angular frequency, if the wind speed is $v$, we expect the the spacing between rows to be $\lambda\sim 2\pi v/N$.  For example, for $\theta \sim 273$ K, a temperature [lapse rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapse_rate) of $\frac{d\theta}{dz}\sim 10$ K/km, and a wind speed of $50$ km/h, we'd expect $\lambda\sim 5$ km, which is consistent with [typically observed spacings](https://www.britannica.com/science/lee-wave) of $2-8$ km.

**Undulatus clouds** (or ["billow clouds"](https://www.eoas.ubc.ca/courses/atsc113/flying/met_concepts/01-met_concepts/01b-special-clouds/billow.html)) are usually just the bottom view of waves generated by [Kelvin–Helmholtz instabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin-Helmholtz_instability) which form perpendicular to the wind direction when the wind shear between two layers of air is large enough to overcome the buoyancy forces keeping the layers separate. [This image from Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:KHI-Physics.jpg) show how the Kelvin-Helmholtz instability starts.

[image: Generation of Kelvin-Helmholtz wave]

Such waves are expected when the [Richardson number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson_number) ($\mathrm{Ri}$) is smaller than about 1/4:

$$\mathrm{Ri} = \frac{\text{buoyancy}}{\text{flow shear}} = \frac{g}{\rho} \frac{\partial \rho/\partial z}{(\partial u / \partial z)^2} $$

where $g$ is the local acceleration due to gravity, $\rho$ is the air density, $z$ is vertical height, and $u$ is the air velocity.

The density difference is usually because of a temperature difference, in which case

$$\mathrm{Ri} \approx g \beta \frac{\Delta T/L}{(\Delta V / L)^2} = g \beta L \frac{\Delta T}{(\Delta V)^2}$$

where is $L$ is the thickness of the unstable shear layer over which the temperature $T$ and velocity $V$ are changing and $\beta$ is the coefficient of thermal expansion of air.
Rolls can form in this shear layer, with the the roll spacing [expected to be](https://doi.org/10.1002/qj.49707733208) about $3$ times the roll height, i.e. $3L$.

If **chemtrail** proponents don't accept your explanations that periodic wavey cloud patterns can form naturally, perhaps they might be more willing to believe Fox News: ["Crazy Clouds! The wave!"](https://fox41blogs.typepad.com/wdrb_weather/2012/08/crazy-clouds-the-wave.html).   You might also ask them how chemtrails could possibly explain this beautiful NASA image of [cloud streets in the Bering Sea](https://www.visibleearth.nasa.gov/images/6243/cloud-streets-in-the-bering-sea). The wind is blowing diagonally from sea ice (upper right) over the warmer sea water in the lower left producing hundreds of parallel stable cloud streets.

[image: Cloud streets flowing off edge of Bering Sea Ice]

You might also note that [lee cloud waves](https://doi.org/10.1186/s40623-023-01767-x) have been observed on Mars. But I suspect conspiracists would just argue that both the Mars and Bering Sea images are NASA fakes.

This wind shear process that drives undulatus cloud formation is closely related to how many other common waves are produced by fluids moving parallel to an interface. If someone believes that chemtrails are the only possible explanation for undulatus clouds, then to be consistent they should also not believe that the wind can produce waves the surface of water, or that water can produce underwater beach sand ripples.

Comment: Wow this answer is so detailed. Thank you!

Comment: just one clarification... why are the convection rolls almost periodical? Can't their size be randomly distributed?

Comment: I added a reference to roll-spacing theory. My *sketchy* non-mathematical feeling is: What convects up, must come down, so wind speeds around a roll are proportional to its width. Shear friction at the roll's top and bottom is proportional to wind speed *squared*, so it is energetically unfavourable for a stable roll's aspect ratio to grow beyond a maximum size. Small rolls get demolished by the stronger wind speeds of these optimal rolls. Different heating and wind conditions can, of course, produce everything from [hexagonal clouds](https://tinyurl.com/bddynf3u) to tornadoes.